# Why do I get "sed: can't read yolov4-tiny-obj.cfg: No such file or directory"

Tags: python, windows, sed, computer-vision, yolo

I'm trying to train tiny yolo for custom objects on google colab, however, I have come across this error. I used similar code to train yolov3, but now I am getting this error. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Here is my code:

```
!cp cfg/yolov4-tiny.cfg cfg/yolov4-tiny-obj.cfg

!sed -i 's/batch=1/batch=64/' cfg/yolov4-tiny-obj.cfg
!sed -i 's/subdivisions=1/subdivisions=16/' cfg/yolov4-tiny-obj.cfg
!sed -i 's/max_batches = 500200/max_batches = 4000/' yolov4-tiny-obj.cfg
!sed -i '610 s@classes=80@classes=2@' yolov4-tiny-obj.cfg
!sed -i '696 s@classes=80@classes=2@' yolov4-tiny-obj.cfg
!sed -i '783 s@classes=80@classes=2@' yolov4-tiny-obj.cfg
!sed -i '603 s@filters=255@filters=21@' yolov4-tiny-obj.cfg
!sed -i '689 s@filters=255@filters=21@' yolov4-tiny-obj.cfg
!sed -i '776 s@filters=255@filters=21@' yolov4-tiny-obj.cfg
```

Here is the output

> sed: can't read yolov4-tiny-obj.cfg: No such file or directory
> sed: can't read yolov4-tiny-obj.cfg: No such file or directory
> sed: can't read yolov4-tiny-obj.cfg: No such file or directory
> sed: can't read yolov4-tiny-obj.cfg: No such file or directory
> sed: can't read yolov4-tiny-obj.cfg: No such file or directory
> sed: can't read yolov4-tiny-obj.cfg: No such file or directory
> sed: can't read yolov4-tiny-obj.cfg: No such file or directory

Comment: At a guess - you forgot to put `cfg/` in front of all but the first 2 of your 9 file names?

Comment: Yes this solved the issue, thank you very much!